# Running SampleApp Message Connection Timeout Error

Tags: java

https://developers.google.com/android/management/sample-app

Running SampleApp Message Connection Timeout Error

The error information is as follows

Creating signup URL...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:656)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1282)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1257)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:283)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:394)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:493)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.adups.emm.servlet.SampleApp.createEnterprise(SampleApp.java:115)
    at com.adups.emm.servlet.SampleApp.run(SampleApp.java:62)
    at com.adups.emm.servlet.SampleApp.main(SampleApp.java:50)
```

Comment: this example has a lot of configuration needed for it to work. Maybe you set something up wrong. Some of the important configurations are: PROJECT_ID, SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDENTIAL_FILE, APP_NAME, setCallbackUrl.

Comment: I don't know what value CallbackUrl sets.